# How to unsubscribe from a loaded event in a derived control?

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I'm just playing with the grid class, to make it "cleaver". So I want to be able to use it in xaml and just specify how many rows I want, or columns etc, to do this I've got the code below. It all works fine, I used the loaded event to add rows and columns, but now I am thinking how should I unsubscribe from this event? I can't find straight forward information of how to do it?

```
public class MyFormGrid : Grid
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Columns", typeof(int), typeof(ASLFormGrid), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RowsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Rows", typeof(int), typeof(ASLFormGrid), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public MyFormGrid()
    {
        Loaded += MyGrid_Loaded;
    }

    public int Columns
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ColumnsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColumnsProperty, value); }
    }

    public int Rows
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(RowsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RowsProperty, value); }
    }

    private void MyGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < Columns; i++)
        {
            ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < Rows; i++)
        {
            RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition(););
        }
    }
}
```

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could easily be put inside your loaded event handler:

```
public class MyFormGrid : Grid
{
    ...
    public MyFormGrid()
    {
        Loaded += MyGrid_Loaded;
    }
    ...
    private void MyGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Loaded -= MyGrid_Loaded;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, I didn't actually think about it. I was thinking that there is some method to override to unhoock. Thank you :)